# Second Order Differential Circuit Equation

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

[Picture of the question.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AONV6.png) I was given this question by my prof, and he also gave us initial values of $V_{c}(0) = V_{A}$, $i_{L}(0) =  0$, and $\frac{di_{L}}{dt} (0) = 0$. However, plugging in $i_{L}$ and $\frac{di_{L}}{dt}$ into the equation I got using the homogenous and inhomogeneous equation tells me that $i_{L} = 0$. This cannot be true since the current should loop around the the inductor capacitor and the second resistor. I think my methods are right, but I could fully be wrong any help on this would be appreciated.

Comment: Why do you not provide the differential equation for the situation you derived?  It is just the discharge of C over R and L so you should get a damped oscillation.

Comment: I don't give the differential equation because no matter which equation you get when substituting in $k_{1}e^{k_{2}t}$ you will get an equation with no particular integral and a homogenous equation with constants A and B which when solved for using the intials above equal 0. The equation I got was $i_{L} = e^{\frac{R_{2}}{2L}t}(Acos( \sqrt{(\frac{R_{2}}{2L})^{2} - \frac{1}{CL}}t) + Bcos( \sqrt{(\frac{R_{2}}{2L})^{2} - \frac{1}{CL}}) t)$

Comment: I used the equation $0 = V_{R2} + V_{L} + V_{c} \iff 0 = iR_{2} + L\frac{di_{L}}{dt} + \frac{1}{C}\int i_{L} dt$ to come to the differential

Comment: The equation above is $Bsin$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The initial condition $\dfrac{di}{dt}=0$ is wrong, you are correct, that with this initial condition you end with $i=0$.

Comment: Since it is listed as an "initial condition" I guess it means $$\left.\frac{di_L}{dt}\right|_{t=0} = 0$$